# reorder content with css for display to support accessibility

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Consider the following html layout. For accessibility and some other reasons I'd prefer the menu to be at the third position in the source.
But visibly the menu should actually appear at the top, before the article.
What are my options for this? (support for IE8 and up)

```
<html>
 <body>
  <article>The article ...</article>
  <aside>something aside</aside>
  <nav>the menu</nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Currently I use "display: table" to much dislike by my collegues like so (http://jsfiddle.net/Dqzyj/):

```
<html>
 <body style="display:table;">
  <article style="display:table-row-group;">The article ...</article>
  <aside style="display:table-row-group;">something aside</aside>
  <nav style="display:table-header-group;">the menu</nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can just use the position property, you can move the nav bar to the top. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Dqzyj/1/

Comment: I'm not a css expert but that sounds like something I didn't want to do. What if the elements are nested? The code above is just an example to support my question. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: If you can use css3 - then flexbox can control the order of child flex elements

Comment: Ah thanks, forgot to mention...ie8 must be supported. But thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want negative margins or absolute positioning or flexbox - then I guess your table solution is the only other way. (At least as far as i know of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an accessibility point of view, I would not recommend re-ordering the elements like that.

We used to take that approach, and although screen reader users might benefit (slightly) from that order, there are also people who rely on the keyboard but can see the screen (e.g. mobility impairments, where people might use a Stephen Hawking-style switch access). [Video example](http://www.assistiveware.com/a-pivotal-role-in-the-household).

Speech recognition can also be negatively impacted by re-ordering in this way, assuming the page has enough content to induce scrolling.

When they (effectively) tab through the page, the focus would appear to skip the visible navigation, making it appear inaccessible. If they did tab through enough to find the navigation, then it would jump back up the page, which is very disorienting. For example, try tabbing through the [Lakeland page](http://www.lakeland.co.uk/) to find the top navigation.

A better solution is to use a skip link above the navigation that goes to the content:
[How to use skip links](http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2004/what-are-skip-links/).

NB: It is an old article so demos a 'skip to navigation' link instead, but the principle is the same.

If the 'other reasons' (SEO perhaps?) mean that you still want to go with a nav-last approach, then could you say why the display-table approach is not liked?

The modern method would be to use flex box and ordering, but that isn't supported pre IE10. Absolute positioning might work, but be careful that zooming the page or text-sizing does not break it. I need a little more info about the problem before suggesting a solution.

Comment: I read about the "skip to content" link when I did my research. But decided against it as I read studies showing impaired people stumble across those links, skip them and still complain they have to go through the whole menu (for example).
The complaint about "display: table" is that it often breaks the layout and making it very difficult to style things, if even possible. This especially applies to third party code: "when I set display: block, it just worked".

Comment: My company tests websites with people who have disabilities quite a lot, I've seen lots of people use both. There isn't a perfect solution, but skip links are better than creating a layout that ignores the DOM order (at least with current methods. Used in combination with ARIA Landmarks (http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/how-aria-landmark-roles-help-screen-reader-users/) it is your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <body style="display:table;">
        <article style="display:table-row-group;">The article ...</article>
        <aside style="display:table-row-group;">something aside</aside>
        <nav style="display:table-row-group;">the menu</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Change nav style from `table-header-group` to `table-row-group`. `table-header-group` can cause the tag move upside.

Comment: Sorry, but moving it up is what was intended.